# cluster_extraction - pcl::search not declared?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I've tried selectively importing the code from the Point Cloud Library Cylinder Model Segmentation [tutorial](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cylinder_segmentation.php#cylinder-segmentation) into the template provided in the ROS PCL [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials).

Trying to run rosmake throws an error:

/ros_workspace/turtlebot_test/src/model_segmentation.cpp:49:8: error: ‘pcl::search’ has not been declared

The tutorials compile and work on my system individually in ROS and using the CMake method described on the PCL website respectively.  I've tried adding headers and library links to the CMake file but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12529/cluster_extraction---pcl::search-not-declared?/) by [TobyLightheart](https://answers.ros.org/users/1607/tobylightheart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you want to use the latest pcl 1.4, download the perception_pcl_unstable package to your ros_workspace so that its looked on top of the perception_pcl path. So in that case the pcl 1.4 will be used in all your compilation.
Use the following command to download the package onto the workspace.

```
svn co https://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_unstable perception_pcl_unstable
```

This is what i did and it worked

Hope this helps,

Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-11**:
Hey, Thank you very much. It solved one of my issues here. http://answers.ros.org/question/3539/installation-of-tabletop_object-detector-package

**Comment by [TobyLightheart](https://answers.ros.org/users/1607/tobylightheart/) on 2012-01-09**:
It turns out what looks like a more general method to include Eigen is described here http://www.ros.org/wiki/eigen  I had put that original include line just before the 'rosbuild_genmsg()' line in the CMakeLists.txt in my test package directory.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-09**:
Hey, May i know where you pasted the include_directories(/usr/include/eigen3) to solve the Eigen/StdVector issue.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-05**:
You are welcome :)

**Comment by [TobyLightheart](https://answers.ros.org/users/1607/tobylightheart/) on 2012-01-05**:
Putting perception_pcl_unstable into my ROS workspace folder has solved that compile error.  The compiler still needed some help finding includes like 'Eigen/StdVector', which I ended up handling by adding 'include_directories(/usr/include/eigen3)' to CMakeLists.txt.  Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first major thing that I would check would be to ensure that you've included all of the necessary header files in your source file.

```
 #include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>
 #include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
 #include <pcl/point_types.h>
 #include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
 #include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
 #include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h>
 #include <pcl/sample_consensus/method_types.h>
 #include <pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h>
 #include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>
```

Next would be to check your manifest.xml for all necessary dependencies:

```
<depend package="pcl" />
<depend package="pcl_ros" />
```

**EDIT**: After reading some documentation and playing with Eclipse code-completion, it seems as though `KdTree` is not under the `search` namespace.

Thus, change:

```
pcl::search::KdTree<PointT>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<PointT> ());
```

To:

```
pcl::KdTree<PointT>::Ptr tree (new pcl::KdTree<PointT> ());
```

And then you're all set.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TobyLightheart](https://answers.ros.org/users/1607/tobylightheart/) on 2012-01-05**:
I'm afraid the change you suggested in the edit gives me a 'cannot allocate abstract type' compile error.  It turns out that the most current release of PCL (1.4), available in the 'perception_pcl_unstable' stack,  does have kdtree in a 'search' namespace, so I've used that. Thanks anyway!

**Comment by [TobyLightheart](https://answers.ros.org/users/1607/tobylightheart/) on 2012-01-05**:
Thanks for the fast reply.  Unfortunately the problem doesn't seem to a lack of those headers or dependencies.  I had added the dependencies and all of those headers except 'pcd_io.h' to the .cpp source file, but that last header didn't remove the compile error.